# Firebase email not verified override

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am creating user password registration in Firebase but have a specific scenario that I cannot understand.

1. User creates the account with someones else's email address (x@gmail.com), not his own.
2. Email verification sent to this account (x@gmail.com)
3. User does not verify this account because it is not his.
4. The user with a real account (x@gmail.com) tries to create an account and gets:
   The email address is already in use by another account.

How to solve this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email verification is not a required step when using the email+password provider, so in step 1 the user is signed in with a valid account. You can block them from accessing data based on the `emailVerified` property, but the account will still exist. If you want to support this scenario with the email+password provider, you'll have to occasionally delete unverified email addresses with the Admin SDK.

Alternatively consider using the [email link provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth), which essentially combines verifying their email address with signing in. And would mean that in step 4 the user is actually signed in.